# Echo não retorna o caminho da imagem no atributo "style" do HTML

Tags: php

Fiz o seguinte

```
echo"<div class='carousel-item active' style='background-image: url('img/intro-carousel/". $row["img_pag_princ_car"] . "')>"
```

Mas está retornando o seguinte:

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url(" img="" intro-carousel="" 01_gigaclima_indoor.jpg')="">
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Porque está substituindo o `/` por  ?

Comment: Melhor [edit] e postar um contexto melhor da sua aplicação. Pode ser algum mecanismo de template, alguma coisa tratando o _output buffer_, alguma configuração, framework agindo em outra parte do código (senão as aspas não estariam alteradas na saída). Da forma como está, apenas com o que tem na pergunta, não dá para reproduzir o problema. Precisamos de mais detalhes ou um [mcve]. - E para piorar a situação, você está usando aspas simples de maneira incorreta na parte HTML, um bom começo seria corrigir isto (aplicando ao `style` e ao `url` dentro de `style`).

Comment: Tem algo estranho. No seu código vc tem `class='carousel-item active'` e na saida tem `class="carousel-item active"`, Ou a saída não é desse código ou esse não é o único código que está gerando essa saída.

Comment: o problema é que aqui `url('` a aspas fecha o atributo `style`, por isso o erro, mas não sei bem como arrumar, tenta escapar com \ assim: `url(\" ... \")` com aspas duplas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema são as aspas, está se perdendo na interpolação. Tente escapar as aspas:

```
echo  "<div class=\"carousel-item active\" style=\"background-image: url('img/intro-carousel/". $a . "')\">";
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo obrigado pela ajuda